# What is the difference between the [entertainment] and [choreography] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Basically, how are the tags [entertainment](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entertainment) and [choreography](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choreography) different? When should a question be one of these, but not the other? Is there a case where a question is about choreography but not entertainment?

Answer (score 1):

To me, [entertainment](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entertainment) is kind of a blanket tag for "this is a piece of fiction where technical accuracy is less important than enjoyment" and [choreography](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choreography) is specifically for questions about the choreography.

Comment: FWIW, I think that [tag:choreography] might also apply to cases where it's for a demonstration, such as the various "Awesome Kung Fu demo!" videos involving highly choreographed sessions involving people dodging spear attacks by head bobs and the like.

Comment: The description in the choreography tag excerpt seems oddly film-specific, but in practice the tag seems like it could cover any kind of choreographed fighting (e.g. film, TV, theatre, etc.). If the community agrees, the tag excerpt and wiki should be updated accordingly.